# Does JavaScript automatically set a time based seed for its random method in the Math object?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript does *not* have a seed method for its Math.random() method.

When "intellisensing" JavaScript's Math object in an IDE, there is no indication that a seed method exists.

**Does the ECMAScript specification say that a seed will be automatically set?**

Perhaps when the first script of an HTML page loads or when a browser is started there is an internal call to seed the RNG.

Answer (score 2):

No. The standard makes virtually no requirements about how `Math.random` is implemented besides this single paragraph:

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.

See https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14